# Apache does not listen to specified port

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4, virtualhost, reverse-proxy, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to establish an Nginx + Apache-with-PHP-module configuration. It worked on Debian 6 with such configuration:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:9002 >
  ServerName mysite.com
  AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
  AssignUserID username username
  CustomLog /var/www/httpd-logs/mysite.com.access.log combined
  DocumentRoot /var/www/username/data/www/mysite.com
  ErrorLog /var/www/httpd-logs/mysite.com.error.log
  AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .phtml
  AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
  php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/username/data:."
  php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir "/var/www/username/data/mod-tmp"
  php_admin_value session.save_path "/var/www/username/data/mod-tmp"
</VirtualHost>
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:9002
<Directory /var/www/username/data/www/mysite.com>
  Options -ExecCGI -Includes
  php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/username/data:."
  php_admin_flag engine on
</Directory>
```

On a new server I am running Ubuntu 16. When I restart apache2 service and run `netstat` there is nothing on 127.0.0.1:9002 (even though apache is running). Nginx, as expected, gives `connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream` error. I've tried:

- Changing the port (9002) to any other port
- Commenting out `NameVirtualHost` directive and changing `VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:9002` to `VirtualHost *:9002`
- Disabling `firewalld` — it was disabled from the beginning
- Checking if apache does load the .conf file — it does (`apache2ctl -S`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `Listen` directive to Apache config.  You could find Listen directives in `httpd.conf` and add there `Listen 9002`.

More information you could find in [Apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/bind.html).

> The Listen directive does not implement Virtual Hosts - it only tells
>   the main server what addresses and ports to listen on. If no
>    directives are used, the server will behave in the same
>   way for all accepted requests. However,  can be used to
>   specify a different behavior for one or more of the addresses or
>   ports. To implement a VirtualHost, the server must first be told to
>   listen to the address and port to be used. Then a 
>   section should be created for the specified address and port to set
>   the behavior of this virtual host. Note that if the  is
>   set for an address and port that the server is not listening to, it
>   cannot be accessed.